# How to run "pbrun pbapp wasapp=ksh" command using SSH java client?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to connect to a ssh  server. I tried Jsch, Orion, J2ssh java api's to connect. I could able to run commands like date, pwd,who etc. But for my purpose, i need to use "`pbrun pbapp wasapp=ksh`" command. Then only, i can use my remaining commands on the server.

Please let me know, how to use this command over java.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work as you expected? What output did you get from the SSH server or remote shell?

Comment: *"I could able to run commands like date, pwd,who etc."*.  What do you mean by this?  Do you mean that you SUCCEEDED in running those commands using the one of the above approaches?  If so, which one?

Comment: In JSch, i opened a channel in "exec" and set command as 'date'. I then captured the result. But when i give that pbrun command.. its keep on running and its not returning any result.

Comment: It may require pseudo-terminal.  Try ChannelExec#setPty(true) before Chennel#connect() .

Comment: i tried.. if i run pbrun command alone.. it is taking me to terminal. i need to print in the string. Also, if i append other command to it.. pbrun is not running.