# Running shell command after expect login

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tcl, expect

Iam trying to exceute a command after logging in to a linux RHEL box using **expect** and **interact**.
Below is script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 100
set temp [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh userid@10.20.30.40
expect "Password:"
send "password\n";
interact
expect "*3.2*"
send "./p.sh\n";
```

Its successfully logging in to the box but after that its not excecuting the command.

This is the actual output of the commnad after login , which iam trying to exceute.

```
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: Sun Mar 22 11:04:01 2015 from com
-sh-3.2$ pbrun pbapp wasapp=ksh

Please note  home directories are intended only for user/application profiles.
$
```

These are the errors i received

```
-sh-3.2$ exit
logout
Connection to 10.20.30.40 closed.
expect: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"expect "*$""
    (file "./testWas.sh" line 8)
```

when i try 
expect "*$"
exec "pwd"

```
-sh-3.2$ exit
logout
Connection to 10.20.30.40 closed.
couldn't execute " pwd ": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec { pwd }"
    (file "./testWas.sh" line 8)
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to red @glenn jackman
iam able to excute pbrun commands after login..

But after excecuting the pbrun command script is exiting

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 100
    set host [lindex $argv 0]
    set username [lindex $argv 1]
    set password [lindex $argv 2]
    set command [lindex $argv 3]
    spawn ssh $username@$host expect "Password:"
    send "$password\n";
    expect -re {\$ $} ; # put here string from your server prompt
    send "./p.sh\n";
    expect -re {\$ $} ; 
    send "pwd\n";
```

This is the content of p.sh
Only first line of the script is executing..

```
-sh-3.2$ cat p.sh
pbrun pbapp wsapp=ksh
pwd
clear
-sh-3.2$
```

There is a similar unanswered question
[How to run "pbrun pbapp wasapp=ksh" command using SSH java client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201946/how-to-run-pbrun-pbapp-wasapp-ksh-command-using-ssh-java-client)

Answer (score 4):

`interact` tells expect that you are going into manual mode, where you, the human, is in control of the spawned command. I see you then typed `exit` which ended the ssh session. Since the spawned command ended, the `interact` command ended and  control returned to the script. The next command dies because the spawned command is not running.

Simply put, remove `interact`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 100
set temp [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh userid@10.20.30.40

expect "Password:"
send "password\r"     # a carriage return more exactly represents
                      # "hitting enter"

expect -re {\$ $}     # this regular expression matches the end of the prompt
send "./p.sh\r"

if { you want to interact manually with the ssh session } {
    interact
} else {
    expect -re {\$ $}     # if p.sh exits the ssh session, remove this line
    send "exit\r"         # and this one too.
    expect eof
}
```

Comment: Okay..Thank you.. I was able to execute the command which is s pbrun command "pbrun pbapp wapp=ksh"  which like SU command will switch the user from my user name nayeem to wapp user which is more privilleged.. but its exiting the script after running it..